# Pandas: map new column to existing column based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, apply

I have a table like this:

| id | q1_score | q2_score | q3_score | q4_score | quarter |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | -0.77 | -0.55 | 0.21 | 3.42 | q1 |
| 2 | -0.77 | -0.55 | 0.21 | 3.42 | q1 |
| 3 | -0.77 | -0.55 | 0.21 | 3.42 | q2 |
| 4 | -0.77 | -0.55 | 0.21 | 3.42 | q3 |
| 5 | -0.77 | -0.55 | 0.21 | 3.42 | q4 |

I want to create a new column `quarter_score` based on the value of `quarter`.

1. If `quarter==q1` then `quarter_score`=value from `q1_score` of that row.
2. If `quarter==q2` then `quarter_score`=value from `q2_score` of that row.
3. so forth ...

My code looks like this

```py
mapper = {'q1': df['q1_score'], 'q2':df['q2_score'], 'q3': df['q3_score'], 'q4': df['q4_score']}
df['quarter_score'] = df['quarter'].map(mapper)
```

but it does not take single value, it takes whole rows for that column for each row.

| id | q1_score | q2_score | q3_score | q4_score | quarter | quarter_score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | -0.77 | -0.55 | 0.21 | 3.42 | q1 | 0 -0.77 1 -0.77 2 -0.77 |
| 2 | -0.77 | -0.55 | 0.21 | 3.42 | q1 | 0 -0.77 1 -0.77 2 -0.77 |
| 3 | -0.77 | -0.55 | 0.21 | 3.42 | q2 | 0 -0.55 1 -0.55 2 -0.55 |
| 4 | -0.77 | -0.55 | 0.21 | 3.42 | q3 | 0 0.21 1 0.21 2 0.21 |
| 5 | -0.77 | -0.55 | 0.21 | 3.42 | q4 | 0 3.42 1 3.42 2 3.42 |

**My final output should be like this below.**

| id | q1_score | q2_score | q3_score | q4_score | quarter | quarter_score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | -0.77 | -0.55 | 0.21 | 3.42 | q1 | -0.77 |
| 2 | -0.77 | -0.55 | 0.21 | 3.42 | q1 | -0.77 |
| 3 | -0.77 | -0.55 | 0.21 | 3.42 | q2 | -0.55 |
| 4 | -0.77 | -0.55 | 0.21 | 3.42 | q3 | 0.21 |
| 5 | -0.77 | -0.55 | 0.21 | 3.42 | q4 | 3.42 |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```py
df["quarter_score"] = df.apply(lambda x: x[x["quarter"] + "_score"], axis=1)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   id  q1_score  q2_score  q3_score  q4_score quarter  quarter_score
0   1     -0.77     -0.55      0.21      3.42      q1          -0.77
1   2     -0.77     -0.55      0.21      3.42      q1          -0.77
2   3     -0.77     -0.55      0.21      3.42      q2          -0.55
3   4     -0.77     -0.55      0.21      3.42      q3           0.21
4   5     -0.77     -0.55      0.21      3.42      q4           3.42
```

Answer (score 3):

For huge datasets, going down to numpy's level can be interesting

```
df['quarter_score'] = df.to_numpy()[np.arange(len(df)), 
                                    df['quarter'].str[-1].astype(int) - 1]
```

Comment: @mmustafaicer just remove the `- 1` then. Should be easy to map this onto your dataframe :p

Comment: And it worked. Thanks. I had some extra columns I had truncated before posting here. That is why it failed first time.